# Is it good thing to only pass a string/text in prop children in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm just curious, is it also a good thing to only pass a string/text in property children of a React component?

For example:

```
...
<SampleComponent children={'Confirm'}/>
...
```

Comment: I've never heard anyone claim this is best practice, and I can't see any reason it would be worthwhile avoiding other/more complex data types.

Comment: I don't see how this could be a "best practices" question, it's just a matter of what you are trying to build. If you need a string, feel free to pass a string. If you need something else, pass something else. For example, it's common to pass JSX elements as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a stone written best practice but the `children` prop in React is globally used to render a slot in the component.

So it is more common to see this kind of children syntax:

```html
<SampleComponent>
  Confirm
</SampleComponent>
```

than this one:

```html
<SampleComponent children="Confirm" />
```

But at the end it's just a matter of taste. Both have exactly the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

The name "children" in props is commonly used to refer to wrapped components when creating wrapper components.
You should use more descriptive names in props, as in your situation probably "result"

Comment: How about using a component from a UI library like MUI. For example the Button component which is the only property that I could change the name of the button is the children prop. I mean, I want to save some lines instead doing this:

<Button>'Confirm'</Button> 

I used: <Button children='Confirm'/>

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/

Comment: As I wrote before, this is not the way. Name of prop should give information. For <Button> text 'Confirm' isn't a children.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your time and giving an answer to my question.